# extracting linkedin recommendations for display on another webpage without log-in

Tags: api, linkedin-api

I am building a wesite for a client who has requested that his LinkedIn recommendations be displayed on one of the pages. Is it possible to do this using the LinkedIn API, or some other tool, without requiring viewers to log-in on the page? Ideally I would like to also be able to control the formatting so that it matches the rest of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/1430

> You can make an API call to http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,recommendations-received) and get the data you need. You should do this each time to make sure you have most up-to-date recommendation entries. But there is no easy widget you can embed. You would need to write code yourself.

Comment: That code also requires that your visitor logs into linked in and authorises your site.